# is there any scala network library with actor model

Tags: scala, networking, actor

i'm now to scala. i need a network library with actor model.
   or the best choise is java.nio?

Answer (score 8):

http://akkasource.org/

'nuff said.

Answer (score 0):

You probably also want to look at Lift's actor lib, given the decently large user base testing it.

http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/1f3f980c5cc791e6?pli=1

http://blog.lostlake.org/index.php?/archives/96-Migrating-from-Scala-Actors-to-Lift-Actors.html